# Unsupported features: Display of formulas in cells

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, excel

I have a number of Excel templates that are stored in SharePoint library. When trying to either view or edit the files in my browser, I get the error message that the browser can't be used because there are unsupported features: "Display of formulas in cells".

As far as I can tell, this is not a feature that is enabled in my workbook, so I'm a bit confused (i.e. when I actually download a file, "Show Formulas" is not selected). Are there other features in Excel that might be triggering this error instead?

Thanks in advance for any help anyone can provide.

Comment: do you have any formula column in the excel workbooks?

Answer (score 0):

From Microsoft documentation, this is the list of things that could rise errors when you try to publish on sharepoint.
Have you checked that you don´t have any of these?

Information Rights Management (IRM) protection.

ActiveX controls.

Embedded smart tags.

PivotTables report with multiple consolidation ranges.

External references (workbooks that contain links to other workbooks).

Workbooks saved in formula view.

XML expansion packs.

XML maps.

Data validation.

Query tables, SharePoint lists, Web queries, and text queries.

Workbooks that reference add-ins.

Workbooks that use the RTD() function.

Workbooks that use workbook and worksheet protection.

Embedded pictures or clip art.

Cell and sheet background pictures.

AutoShapes and WordArt.

Ink annotations.

Organization charts and diagrams.

DDE links.